# Turn array to chain methods

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array like this...

```
$data = [
    'columns' => [
        [['increments', 'id']],
        [['string', 'key'], ['index']],
        [['text', 'value']],
    ]
];
```

The first value is the function name, the second value is an arg/args (parameters). I want each to be run like this ($table)...

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('key')->index();
$table->text('value');
```

I've tried to iterate the array with a loop, and used function as array [ $functionName($params) ] method as well as "call_user_func". But failed. What would be the best way to call these, one by one like the above example?

Comment: This is a "dirty" way of doing things. What's your end goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @IslamElshobokshy mentioned, this is a dubious request, which may mean your design is flawed/inefficient to begin with.

If you really need to do it, try something like this:

```
foreach ($data['columns'] as $calls) {
  $currentValue = $table;
  foreach ($calls as $call) {
    $methodName = $call[0];
    $methodArgs = array_slice($call, 1);
    $currentValue = $currentValue->$methodName(...$methodArgs);
  }
}
```

This makes use of [variable functions/methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) and [argument unpacking](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking).